# I recently started using VPS CENTOS 7.5 kvm [server1] v76.0.15 with cpanel

Tags: server, cpanel, vps, whm, namecheap

After configuring the WHM/cPanel the landing page does not show the index.html in public_html rather it is showing the domain registrar details e.g: www.nexnaira.com.

I have deleted all the files in the public_html (cPanel) but it seems not to have any effect like the site is not pointing to the index.html I uploaded. Maybe I am doing it all wrong, please I need assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your domain to display the content it has on your VPS, it is necessary to either register Private Nameservers or point your domain to BasicDNS and then add A record with the IP Address of your server in order to point it to your VPS.

To register Private Nameservers three steps should be taken:
1) register Private Nameservers on the Domain registrar's side;
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/768/10/how-do-i-register-personal-nameservers-for-my-domain

You can find the IP addressees for your Private Nameservers in. Your Virtual server access details should have been sent to your registered email.

2) set up Private Nameserves on the Hosting provider side ( SOA record which states the privary nameserver for your domain, A records for subdomains ns1 and ns2 and NS records) This guide is for your convenience: 
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/207/48/how-to-set-up-private-nameservers-vps-and-dedicated-servers

3) point your domain to the Private Nameservers on the Domain registrar's side.

Mind you I am using these reference links because I am using Namecheap hosting services

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your default name servers of domain from domain control panel.
Also you need to create child name servers for your domain .
please follow the below tutorial to setup . Once you done setup in your WHM/cPanel, you need to create the same child nameservers using your domain control panel.

[Create Child name servers](https://www.ucartz.com/clients/index.php?rp=/knowledgebase/23/How-to-configure-custom-name-servers.html)